# Doing a web live-preview of an Ionic Application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I was browsing ionic themes and I found a plugin on their pages which showcase their mobile application based on Ionic.

[Script](https://ionicthemes.com/product/bazaar-ionic-multi-app-template/envato-live-preview?utm_source=codecanyon&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=live_preview)

I was wondering where does this script come from and if there is a possibility to do the same on a website to showcase the demo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need any special script to do this.

Just put `www` folder to your web server and put `<iframe>` on your website like this to showcase your app demo:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/myapp/" width="320" height="568"></iframe>
```